# I am using unity to make my first 2d game (im a noob) and i tried to make a death barrier that will teleport the charecter back to the start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

(just so you know, im a noob at this so if you recognise some of the code it might of come from  tutorials because i do not know C# and only know the parts that are similar to arduino and java; some of the code from the tutorials were edited so i cannot troubleshoot by looking at them; i have browsed the web)

also, it uses the sunnyland and free platform assets packs from the asset store because i am not an artist

so, i was trying to make a death barrier for the tutorial level (which is the only level in the platformer at the time of writing) and it didn't really work, so i tweaked the code until i got this:

```
public Transform respawnArea;
public GameObject player;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    Debug.Log("the player has died"); //this is how i noticed the problem
    player.transform.position = respawnArea.transform.position;
}
```

after that, i tested it and then it seemed to not work but then some further testing proved that the sprite was falling past the barrier but the collisions were teleporting where the should of went. i tested it with the debug and when the player fell through it reported it to debug but then i tried walking left (into a wall) and watched the debug and nothing happened but when i jumped over the wall, the invisible hitbox fell back into the death barrier and it gave me another debug. the weird thing is, when i pause the sprite appears where it would be and when i resume it disappears again. (again, im a unity and C# noob so this might be normal and have nothing related to the problem)

Unity Version: 2019.4.0f1
Unity hub is installed 
Free version

Comment: does your death barrier and player have a collider?

Comment: they both have a collider, its just the player's hitbox is getting teleported to the start but not the actual animation

Comment: 2d box collider

Comment: can someone plz reply

Comment: I have a few questions:
What is this script attached to?
How did you do the animations? Do you have a side script controlling the animations?

Comment: the script is attached to the death barrier, and the animations were made using the "animation" and "animator" tabs in the editor. I don't think i have a side script because i just used the animator but once again im new here so i dont know

Comment: reply plz if you can i dont that much have time

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should have a player object with a 2d collider set to trigger (checking the little box on the inspector "IsTrigger"). Also, the death barrier probably should have that checkbox marked.

Comment: they are both on IsTrigger and the same problem persists: the hitbox teleports but not the animation dosnt